# Sync and Encrypt

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, sync, mirroring

My question is quite similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/332315/file-based-encrypt-and-sync-solution-for-windows) but the difference is that I want the sync application to encrypt the files before it puts them in the destination and also the destination is accessed by FTP. It's a network hard drive that's going to be at another location.

I have tried [Allway Sync](http://allwaysync.com/) and it got to the end but then kept crashing on the last step. I have also tried [Cobian Backup](http://www.cobiansoft.com/index.htm) which is an amazing piece of free backup software. It does the encryption just like I want but the problem is that it wants to encrypt the whole backup to a local temp folder first and then copy it all across instead of just doing a few files at a time. I have 360GB of files so that isn't an option. I'm using windows 7 ultimate.

Anyone know of some software (preferably free) that will do this?

It needs to be able to mirror the source directory (remove deleted files from the source on the network drive as well), and also work incrementally, I can't have it try and copy 360GB each night across the internet a it would never finish and cost a fortune!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am very fond of the free [Comodo Backup](http://www.comodo.com/home/free/free-protection.php) (Search for Comodo Backup in the list on the right side and click the link  "Free Download"). It does encrypt the data while transferring it, but I have not yet used it to encrypt individual files.

Comment: It looks good but doesn't work for me because if you select the type 'synchronise' it won't let you use an ftp server and also it won't let you encrypt the files (when using the synchronise option). Thanks anyway.